# How to identify the reason for getting NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, django-views

I have a function where a user can change the BooleanField from False to True. My issue is that after submitting the button in the view I have redirected the page to be the same but for some reason I can't identify I am getting `NoReverseMatch` I have written the name of the app before the name and everything correctly. I need to understand the reason when identified to avoid it in future

Here is the complete error appearing:

```
Reverse for 'designer-only-posts' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['usersheet/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']
```

Here is the models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    request_settle = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Here is the views.py

```
class DesignerOnlyPostListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "designer_only_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Item.objects.filter(designer=user).order_by('-timestamp')

def change_status(request, pk):
    item = Item.objects.get(id=pk)
    item.request_settle = True
    item.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Item Status has been Change To Active')
    return redirect('core:designer-only-posts')
```

Here is the urls.py

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('bla/<int:pk>/', views.change_status, name='bla'),
    path('usersheet/<str:username>', DesignerOnlyPostListView.as_view(),
         name='designer-only-posts'),
]
```

Here is the template:

```
 <a href="{% url 'core:bla' item.pk %}">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit button</button>
 </a>
```

I would like also to understand the steps for debugging the No Reverse Match errors

Comment: You passed `items`, not an `item` to the template.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The change_status function is separate from the ListView if this is what you mean

Comment: But the template you show is from the listview, right?

Comment: Furthermore the error you post is *not* for the `{% url ... %}` you post here. But for a `{% url 'core:designer-only-posts ... %}'.

Comment: Thank you I understood what you are implying, but even if the error is showing that the line with error is `return redirect('core:designer-only-posts')`

Comment: that is also possible, here you are missing the username, it should be something like `return redirect('core:designer-only-posts', username=...)` (with ... an expression that produces the username you need).

Comment: How do I set it to be the current user. So that the `return redirect('core:designer-only-posts', username=....the current logged in user..)` same as get_queryset

Comment: `return redirect('core:designer-only-posts', username=request.user.username)`

Comment: Thank you this is the correct answer if you posted it I will accept it. Many thanks it is working perfectly as I want now